# mailchimp integration in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, mailchimp

Now am heard about `mailchimp` for **effective email marketting**

**So i downloaded it** form [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mage-monkey-mailchimp-integration-4865.html)

But i have few questions

1. whta is the advantage of mailchimp ?
2. Better tutorial for mailchimp ?
3. Better tutorial for mailchimp ?

Anybody please help me

```
I want to integrate mailchimp  in magento
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: You have linked to the deprecated module - the one in current development is here -> http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mage-monkey-mailchimp-integration-4865.html

Comment: Tangential English Lesson: You don't have a few **doubts**, you have a few **questions**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advantages...

Using the Magento newsletter function will probably get you banned from sending email from your web server. Most hosting plans put a limit on the amount of transactional emails that can be sent for the following reason. If they end up sending too much spam-like email, they will be put on block lists and then all their customers get penalized for a few bad players.

They would rather that you send promotional email which can bounce, or end up being marked as unsolicited commercial email through an email service provider that monitors and cleans up any activities that cause unnecessary junk mail to enter the system and also limits through TOS, where lists can come from (existing customers, people who've subscribed, people who wish to receive promotional email and have signed up through other means).

Mail Chimp is one such email service provider, there are several, a couple have created integration modules for Magento so you don't have to export your newsletter subscribers and import them into the email service.

Mail Chimp also is able to give you statistics and will tie into Google Analytics so you can start tracking how effective your promotional emails are, can try different approaches and see what really works and what customers were interested in on the promotional email through link referral from each item you've included. With Magento, you sling stuff at a wall and hope something sticks, with the statistics Mail Chimp can tell you what you flung at the wall, how hard you flung it, how sticky it was and whether people prefer popsicles and chocolate truffles over candy apples and lemon drops. From this you can go from "Meh, whatever..." responses to "Hmm, I think I want this".

Any email service provider you choose can offer this type of statistics and analysis... Magento Newsletter can't.

Comment: +1 - well put and good point about the analytics. 'With Magento, you sling stuff at a wall' - this is very true, and it's normally your own head.

Comment: @Fiasco Labs how mailchimp do these all 
can you please provide some links and examples that i can reffer

Comment: Well, the first step is, under a certain quantity of subscribers, Mail Chimp is free, so you can sign up for an account and actually get hands on experience seeing how it works by putting yourself and a couple work associates in a test mailing list. Have the test email be a piece of promotional email that points to your website, click through the links and if you've tied into Google Analytics, make a test purchase or two. The statistics are pretty easy to figure out, the Google Analytics portion needs your website to have already been set up with it.

Comment: We never bothered with the integration module as we just had the website users sign up for the newsletter, imported them into MailChimp when we started using it and then disabled the Magento newsletter function and put up a MailChimp newsletter signup page in its place and integrated that into Magento. MailChimp's form builder does it for you, the customer then interacts with MailChimp to maintain their subscription.

Comment: @Fiasco Labs - Another good point. Depending on the numbers you are importing, Mailchimp can be a bit funny about it. I once imported 1000 or so addresses from a Wordpress signup list and had to answer quite a lot of questions from their compliance team about it (and that was on quite a big paid-for account).

Comment: Yep, got hit with that one, you don't want to build too quickly as they are adamant that paid lists **never** be used. We were moving from Ratepoint who discontinued doing promotional email so the list was legitimate. They've been burned too often by the spam crowd, so you'd better not be buying, scraping and spamming. It guarantees a lower spamblock rate on the delivery end which is what you want as an advertiser. Another thing that you have to intensely research and adjust for if you're using the Magento Newsletter. SPF records, DomainKeys, etc which you probably have no control over.

Comment: And as I've mentioned, Mail Chimp is free if you don't exceed a certain amount in your subscriber list. Once you have that free account, you have access to all their tutorials which is far better information than anything that can be posted here. They've built everything once you get there to be bone simple for the person who's had no experience sending promotional email. Our problem was that we had to get the cutting torch out to cut off the training wheels as there's such a thing as too simple. Yes, you do want your own company template, and yes, they will allow it when you get to that point

Answer (score 2):

This is copy/pasted straight out of a proposal I recently submitted for a Magento site with integration with a 3rd party newsletter system (in this case I am using the Fontis Campaign Monitor module, which I like);

"
The default Magento email newsletter functionality is not as good as it could be. I would normally hook the email newsletter submission box up to a service like MailChimp or Campaign Monitor (I'd recommend the latter).

They allow you to manage your distribution lists and generate and customise email templates yourself which will actually arrive at the inboxes of your customers and not get spammed, bounced or look awful in their email client.  These systems allow you to test your newsletter in a huge range of email clients and will advise you of any mistakes you've made (ie badly chosen spammable keywords).

They will allow you to send the comapigns to your distribution lists from thier server, and will also give statistics on your email campaigns – bounce rate, open rate, click through rate, numbers flagged as spam, users who unsubscribed, all the different geographies they went to etc.

And they are free until you get about 2000 recipients, after which you pay a small amount for a very good service.
"

Answer (score 2):

You can find examples and demos in [Third-Party API Wrappers for PHP](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738166-api-wrappers) repositories.